# Repeat texture in shader with linear filter in webgl

Tags: textures, webgl, shader

I'm trying to repeat my simple texture in my shader and getting annoying result [image: Line]

The texture wrap property is set to CLAMP_TO_EDGE because i cannot be sure about the size of the image - and for using REPEAT the image must be power of 2 sized.

My fragment use this simple code

```
uniform sampler2D tex1;
void main()
{
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex1, fract(gl_TexCoord[0].xy * 2));
}
```

The result is :

[image: result]

The problems are the joints. when repeat starts. (marked in red)
When filter is nearest there is no problem - the edges are not smooth-ens so no problems.

I created my image in size 16x16 - to be able to use REPEAT filter just for the checking, and the results are good as shown here.

[image: wanted result]

In my real application, i'm letting the user pick the repeat image and it doesn't have to be powered by 2 sized.

Also when i'm using in another app texture atlas, the REPEAT filter is not good anyway. because i'm cutting part of the texture and repeating it.

Can anyone help me solved this issue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can't interpolate if you don't have the data to interpolate with. This is what happens when you do that at the edges with gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE, you interpolate with the edge data alone, not that of the 'next' texture.

Three options come to mind

1. Render (part of) the texture to another texture that is a power of 2 texture, but then you have double AA
2. Implement your own repeat and interpolation algorithms inside the shader. I wager this is the slower option.
3. Blur the edges after drawing the textures or scale the texture up a little bit and blend. I don't think this will always look as intended though. I wouldn't go for it myself

Comment: I have a big texture atlas with allot of sub images inside, so i cannot create all sub images into textures. cause also i'm using this texture for many triangles with many different sub image. How web gl does it when he get REPEAT as the filter. this is the question

Comment: I'm assuming you don't scale every image inside the atlas up to much by making it a power of 2. In that case, using multiple smaller textures should not be a problem. You're using more textures so there's a bit more overhead, but you'll have only those textures you're actually using in texture memory so it has the potential to be more efficient. 

If you want to draw every texture in a single draw call then neither repeat nor linear interpolation would work correctly anyway so it's option 2.